# Add fixed positioned layer to FlowPane

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have a FlowPane with panels which will be used to display data in front of the user.

![enter image description here][1]

I added also scrollpane when the number of the panels is bigger than the visible area. 
I also want to add filter which will sort the panels by type and will display only the appropriate. The red area will hold the ComboBox which will be the filter.

And as you can see the red are pushes down the FlowPane which will make a gap between the top component and the scroll when I make the area transparent.

Is there a way to use the z-index and place the red are in front of the FlowPane? Or some other solution?

This is the result that I would like to get:

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: Please close this one as the new question has better wording/is way easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigate this example based on your code in previous questions:

```
public class Demo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(infrastructurePane(), getFilterPane());
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public Pane getFilterPane() {
        ObservableList<String> options =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3");
        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>(options);

        HBox pane = new HBox();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255,0,85,0.4)");
        pane.getChildren().add(combo);
        pane.setMaxHeight(40);
        // Optional
        //pane.setEffect(new DropShadow(15, Color.RED));
        return pane;
    }

    public ScrollPane infrastructurePane() {

        final FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
        flow.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        flow.setVgap(5);
        flow.setHgap(5);
        flow.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        final ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();

        scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Horizontal scroll bar
        scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);    // Vertical scroll bar
        scroll.setFitToHeight(true);
        scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
        scroll.setContent(flow);
//        scroll.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
//            @Override
//            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> ov, Bounds oldBounds, Bounds bounds) {
//                flow.setPrefWidth(bounds.getWidth());
//                flow.setPrefHeight(bounds.getHeight());
//            }
//        });

        //flow.setPrefWrapLength(170); // preferred width allows for two columns
        flow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");

        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
            flow.getChildren().add(generateRectangle());
        }

        String cssURL = "/com/dx57dc/css/ButtonsDemo.css";
        String css = this.getClass().getResource(cssURL).toExternalForm();
        flow.getStylesheets().add(css);

        return scroll;
    }

    public Rectangle generateRectangle() {

        final Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10);
        rect2.setId("app");
        rect2.setArcHeight(8);
        rect2.setArcWidth(8);
        //rect2.setX(10);
        //rect2.setY(160);
        rect2.setStrokeWidth(1);
        rect2.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        rect2.setWidth(220);
        rect2.setHeight(180);

        rect2.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                rect2.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);
            }
        });

        return rect2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
As per comment, here is the combo without pane. Since there is no pane the mouse events will not be blocked. Replace only this method with above one:

```
public ComboBox getFilterPane() {
    ObservableList<String> options =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3");
    ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>(options);
    combo.setTranslateX(10);
    combo.setTranslateY(10);
    return combo;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm looking for. By the way one idea came to my mind. It's not very good looking when the Combo box is over the panel. Can for example push down the panels or alternative will be to make it almost transparent. Any other ideas?

Comment: @PeterPenzov. Pushing down the panel is not the option, because when the rectangles scroll up they still will stay under the combobox's panel. Otherwise you can just put the combobox panel and stackpane into VBox. You can make the combobox's panel full transparent by not setting the background color of it, please investigate the code above.

Comment: @PeterPenzov, And off-topic, I think one day you may choose to open source your app, since we are (as developers here at SO) contributing to its development step by step, and further contributions will be more easy than seeing only the screenshots as in the question :). Just joking.

Comment: Actually this is my graduate work and it's GPL licensed.

Comment: @PeterPenzov. Hmm take it easy and good luck!

Comment: Ok, thank you!. I have one idea. Can I use margin for the FlowPane to push the panels below?

Comment: @PeterPenzov. You cannot know without trying it! Do flow.setPadding(new Insets(75, 5, 5, 5)); in above code.

Comment: It turns out that it's simple than I think. Thank you!

Comment: I have to ask you one more thing related to this topic. I have a Contextmenu which is called when I right mouse click on the FlowPane. Since I have a transparent layer over the FlowPane I cannot call the Context Menu on all FlowPane area. And I have different context menus for the FlowPane and the panels I cannot easy solve this issue. Any ideas how this issue can be solved?

Comment: @PeterPenzov see update. And please start a new entry for further questions.

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using JavaFX 8, you can try a Notification Pane from [ControlsFX project](http://www.controlsfx.org/)

It looks like:

[image]

Comment: ControlsFX is embeded into java 8 or I have to add it as external jav library?

Comment: Is there other solution with JavafX 2.2?

Comment: ControlsFX third-party open source library for Java 8 only. I'm not aware of similar component for JavaFX 2.2, but I may be wrong

Comment: Ok, can you propose other solution?

Comment: Only one... take a look at the code for NotificationPane (it is an open source project after all), and port it to JavaFX 2.2. It should be a fairly simple task.
Here is the link: https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/4d20cad7c665c73387b751c2e5a7619a32834813/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/control/NotificationPane.java?at=default

Comment: @eugener Not necessarily that simple as it uses components only available in JavaFX 8 believe...

Comment: It's hard to understand if the OP wants the pane to cover the underlying flowpane or not... (a stackpane for the former, a vbox shrinking its first row for the latter should do the job). The only tricky parts: making it a proper re-usable and configurable component (not needed here), and the sliding animation (again, not asked by the OP).

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty unclear to get which behaviour you don't want and which one you want.

This sentence "And as you can see the red are pushes down the FlowPane which will make a gap between the top component and the scroll when I make the area transparent." is particularly hard to understand.

But if you just want to "use the z-index and place the red are in front of the FlowPane?", maybe all you're asking for is just a StackPane ?

> StackPane lays out its children in a back-to-front stack.
>
> The z-order of the children is defined by the order of the children
>   list with the 0th child being the bottom and last child on top. If a
>   border and/or padding have been set, the children will be layed out
>   within those insets.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want the red area be part of the ScrollPane:

- Create a VBox
- Add The Red Area Component to VBox
- Add the FlowPane to VBox
- Set VBox as the ScrollPanes Content

If the Layout with VBox's doenst look statisfying try Borderpane and set the "Red Area" top and your flowpane as center.

---

> Is there a way to use the z-index and place the red are in front of the FlowPane? Or some other solution?

see [QuidNovi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18221620/2549748)