# Add fixed positioned Combobox inside FlowPane

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have a `FlowPane` which will hold many panels which are based on `BorderPane`.

[image]

I want to create `ComboBox` which will be used to filter the Panels by type. And the panels will be scrolled by `ScrollPane`when they exceed the visible area.

I want the combo box to scroll along with the FlowPane inside the ScrollPane. I want to get the result which is displayed into the picture. Can you tell me how I can get the desired result. I can very easy create BorderPanes and insert them into the `FlowPane` and the challenge is how to position the Combo Box and keep it always at this position.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add fixed positioned layer to FlowPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217586/add-fixed-positioned-layer-to-flowpane)

Comment: This one is way easier to understand, please downvote/close the other one.

Comment: @Peter Penzov
Dude, don't create duplicates of your questions: answer comments so that your initial question can be improved by editing! Your initial question should now be closed/downvoted because it has poor wording and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use another border pane?

1. Add your combobox to the top ( or additional flow pane with combobox on
   it)
2. Add your Flowpane to the Center
3. Then scroll the  whole border pane using the scrollpane?

What could be simpler?

Comment: Then the combobox panel wouldn't stay always on top (like a css fixed position). It would be scrolled with the borderpane.

Comment: That is what he was asking for: `I want the combo box to scroll along with the FlowPane inside the ScrollPane.`

Comment: "and the challenge is how to position the Combo Box and keep it always at this position." => His question is actually still pretty ambiguous.

Comment: It would be clear if the screenshot displayed the scrollpane actually being scrolled. Here you can't tell if he wants the combobox "always at this position" or "scrolling along".

Comment: The scroll bar seems to cover the panel with combobox, which tells me that it should scroll together with the rest of the controls.

Comment: Actually, if you'd want this panel to be in fixed position, it would be ugly to have it recover the scrollbar. So you'd make it have a width of (scrollpane.width - scrollbar.width). Resulting in the same picture. I'm not saying you ain't right ;) Just that the formulation is plain ambiguous.

Comment: it is ambiguous... we'd have to wait for Peter's response

Comment: Well, problem is solved. See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217586/add-fixed-positioned-layer-to-flowpane

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd do it:

StackPane with 2 layers:

- layer1: your ComboBox panel.
- layer2: your ScrollPane with your FlowPane inside*.

*The trick is: just make your combobox panel background opaque, and some initial **top inset** on the flowpane so that it starts at the right place.